# How to pass multiple parameter in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have url that I want to rewrite so it can pass the parameter like this

**From** `www.example.com/questions.php/postid=101&title=htaccess_tuts`

**To**   `www.example.com/questions.php/postid/1/title/htaccess_tuts`

I have been trying to get this done using below .htaccess but i end up getting this

**From** `www.example.com/questions.php/postid=1&title=htaccess_tuts`

**To**   `www.example.com/questions.php/postid/101`

The title part didn't show.
Can anyone help me pass it multiple parameter

```
RewriteBase /
#Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]


#here is the problem i have don this but didn't work
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+questions\.php\?postid=([^\s&]+)&([^\s&]+) [NC]
#What can i do again?
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+questions\.php\?postid=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ questions/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^questions/([^/]+)/?$ questions.php?postid=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^questions\.php/postid/([^/]*)/title/([^/]*)$ /questions.php?postid=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

you can use [this](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php) site for generate rewrite rules

Comment: Still not working is taking me to 404.php page @smoqadam

Comment: you can access to this page by `www.example.com/questions.php/postid/1/title/htaccess_tuts` url. did you try it or use other url ?